# Is every positive integer the sum of at most 8 pentatope numbers?

Tags: number-theory

Is every positive integer the sum of at most 8 pentatope numbers ?

See : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatope_number

I saw this conjecture here : http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=912

I wonder if this has been studied before.

A counterexample may be found by a computer perhaps.
I do not see how to disprove it otherwise if its false.

Also I have no clue how to prove it if its true.

Answer (score 1):

It may be hard to find a proof or a counter-example, since the lower-dimensional [Pollock's conjectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollock_octahedral_numbers_conjecture) are still conjectures, too.

Comment: Well perhaps a computer can show that a 7 digit number is not the sum of 8 pentatope numbers. 
Also similar looking conjectures are not neccessarily of the same difficulty. There are many cases in math where higher dimensions turn out to be simpler then lower ones. And even generalizations are sometimes helpfull for a proof.

Comment: I believe that a counterexample, if existing, is really huge (a seven digit number is just a drop in the ocean in this context), since the representation function, in average, should grow like $n^{8/5}$.